# How to use binary search to find the first non-null element in an array?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Assume I have an array of consecutive data and consecutive nulls, e.g.:

`0, 3, 1, 2, null, null, null`

How to use binary search idea to find index of the first null element?

Comment: Binary search algorithm itself cannot help, but its *idea* can.

Comment: binarysearch is only used in sorted arrays and this array is not sorted. Also, even if it was sorted, where r u gonna put null's. R they greater than 0 or what?

Comment: @smttsp It is 'sorted' in the sense that it's in this format - `"number, number, ..., number, null, null, ..., null"`. It's easy enough to apply binary search to this, as you can see from the answers. And please try not to use slang abbreviations - `"... where are you going to put null's. Are ..."`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example solution written in Go, with O(log(n)) time complexity:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func findIn(array []int) {
    fmt.Printf("%v ", array)

    if len(array) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Not Found")
        return
    }

    for low, high, mid := 0, len(array), len(array)/2; ; {

        // terminate search when high meets mid
        if high-mid == 1 {
            if array[mid] == -1 {
                fmt.Println(mid)
                return
            }
            if high == len(array) {
                fmt.Println("Not Found")
                return
            }
            fmt.Println(high)
            return
        }

        // search lower half if middle is -1, otherwise search upper half
        if array[mid] == -1 {
            high = mid
            mid = low + (mid-low)/2
        } else {
            low = mid
            mid = mid + (high-mid)/2
        }
    }

    fmt.Println()
}

func main() {
    findIn([]int{})
    findIn([]int{8})
    findIn([]int{-1})
    findIn([]int{8, -1, -1, -1})
    findIn([]int{8, 9, 7, -1, -1, -1})
    findIn([]int{8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, -1, -1})
}
```

Output:

```
[] Not Found
[8] Not Found
[-1] 0
[8 -1 -1 -1] 1
[8 9 7 -1 -1 -1] 3
[8 9 7 6 5 4 -1 -1] 6
```

Please feel free to suggest a better/shorter solution.

Comment: Just code is not very likely to teach anyone anything and you don't (or at least shouldn't) post a question on [so] if you don't want to learn something. It always helps to add a few words saying what your code does. Possibly some readable pseudo-code as well, or even instead of actual code. Readable pseudo-code or an explanation will also make the answer applicable if it's homework.

Comment: thanks Dukeling, I've modified the answer and added in some code comments

Comment: If I noticed that you're the one who asked the question (my bad) I probably wouldn't have posted the comment, but always something to keep in mind none the less.

Answer (score 4):

Same as regular binary search only treat NULL like the value infinity (max int) and everything else like the value 0. That way the array looks like

```
0, 0, 0, 0, MAX_INT, MAX_INT, MAX_INT
```

At which point run normal binary search for the first MAX_INT on it

Comment: "for MAX_INT" => "for the first MAX_INT"

Comment: The first match is not desired here. The left-most one is. For this, you need to divide until you find two consecutive elements one of which is MAX_INT and the other isn't.

Comment: I have written a (not-so-good) solution, it uses binary search idea to find approximate index of the first non-null element, by "approximate" I mean the solution's answer is usually off by one or two (that's why it is not-so-good).

Comment: @HowardGuo It's not Benjamin's fault if your implementation is broken. Post the code, and someone will look over it. See my previous comment as it mentions a potential pitfall

Comment: I didn't say it is Benjamin's fault, I just told the story of why I asked the question. My solution is ugly and I am looking for a complete and correct solution here.

Comment: @HowardGuo I told you how what the basic idea is and Jan Dvorak gave you even more advice (and helped my momentarily confusion). This is likely your homework which is why we try to give you answers that _guide_ you towards the correct solution and not give you a complete implementation.

Comment: Much appreciated. This is Not a homework, and my (not-so-good) solution was committed long time ago at https://github.com/HouzuoGuo/Aurinko2/blob/master/src/main/scala/net/houzuo/aurinko2/storage/AppendFile.scala . It is a slightly different version of the question I asked here, that is why I did *not* post my solution and ask why my solution has off-by-one error.

Comment: I have written a solution without off-by-any error, thanks you guys anyway.

Comment: @HowardGuo oh, I just saw your response, sorry. I'm glad you worked it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Do a binary search as follows:

- Start in the middle (as one does with binary search)
- When you find a not-`null`, binary search to the right
- When you find a `null`, check the element to the left

  - If it's `null`, binary search to the left
  - If it's not-`null` (or there is no element to the left, since we're already at the left-most element) we found the index of the first `null`

**Some simple pseudo-code:**

```java
int search(start, end):
  // terminating check - should always be the first null
  if start == end
    // sanity check - make sure it's correct
    assert(input[start] == null && (start == 0 || input[start-1] != null))
    return start

  mid = (start+end)/2

  if input[mid] != null
    return search(mid, end) // search right
  else if mid == 0 || input[mid-1] != null // check element to left
    return mid // found
  else
    return search(start, mid) // search left
```

Comment: the idea sounds about right, despite the terminate condition `If it's not-null we found the item`, it will terminate search prematurely given input [null null null null null]

Comment: @HowardGuo If given an all-`null` input, it will search until it gets to the left-most element, then there will exist no element to the left (nothing it technically "not-null"), in which case we found the item. But I edited to have the high-level solution description (the pseudo-code already does) to account for the left-most element case.

Answer (score 0):

Simple brute force with O(n) is likely ideal here since it is equally likely to miss first occurrence of Null when divide and conquer the collection.

Comment: My use case is to search for first appearance of null in very large binary files, which may benefit from the idea of binary search and reduce number of IOs.

Comment: Yes. O(log n) is always better than O(n). No doubt about it. But my concern was when you divide your collection, it is less likely you  land on first occurrence of the Null. Therefore, margin of error is high in BS. So find an alternative approach which is better than O(n) or go with O(n).

Comment: Binary search won't 'miss' the first occurrence if done right. One way, for example, is just looking at the previous element when you find a `null` to determine whether or not it's the first `null`.

Comment: @Nair if you can incorporate Dukeling's comment in your answer, then this a nice answer.